# Read out data from array in json file with dynamic object selection

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, variables

```js
   
var storeid = window.location.hash.substr(1);


var getjson = new XMLHttpRequest();
getjson.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var pos = jsondata.data.findIndex(i => i.id === storeid); 


    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsondata.data[pos].title;
  }
};
getjson.open("GET", "data.json", true);
getjson.send();
```

```html
<p id="demo" style="color: red;"></p>
```

On my website, I want to fill in data from a JSON file. The data should be defined by a variable which corresponds to the property id within a array of objects.

The JSON file:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"id": "airbus", "title" : "Airbus"},
        {"id": "boeing", "title" : "Boeing"},
        {"id": "bombardier", "title" : "Bombardier"},
        {"id": "cessna", "title" : "Cessna"}
    ]
}
```

The javascript I have now

```
if (document.getElementById) { window.onload = getid };

function getid() {
var storeid = window.location.hash.substr(1);
document.getElementById("storeid").innerHTML = storeid;
}

var getjson = new XMLHttpRequest();
getjson.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    var jsondata = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    var pos = jsondata.data.findIndex(i => i.id === "boeing"); 

    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jsondata.data[pos].title;
  }
};
getjson.open("GET", "data.json", true);
getjson.send();
```

Now "boeing" at the 7 line should be defined by the variable storeid.

The final result should show the title of the, by the variable defined, id.

I'm an absolute beginner to JavaScript. So I don't know if you used to correct words to describe. Hopefully you understand it anyway.

Comment: You haven't described how your process fails to work

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: The posted code works. I just don't know how to add this in.

Comment: change line 7 to use storeid?: `i => i.id === storeid`

Comment: `var pos = jsondata.data.findIndex(i => i.id === storeid);`?

Comment: @Ele How can i implement this

Comment: @NickParsoms This doesn't work for me
Edit: It gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: If using the variable `storeid` is not what you're looking for, then you have an X/Y problem here.

Comment: Can you create a [mre] of your issue please. Preferably using a [code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). That way we can help debug your code.

Comment: Probably the problem is because the code to define the variable doesn't gives the correct output. This code should get the data after the hash:
if (document.getElementById) { window.onload = getid };

`function getid() {
var storeid = window.location.hash.substr(1);
document.getElementById("storeid").innerHTML = storeid;
}`

Comment: @NickParsons I made a Code snippet but probably it doesn't work because you can't define a url.

Comment: @Wolffe2 your issue is that `storeid` is defined inside of the function `getid()`, so it is only available within that function (its scope is function-scoped). You either need to `return` the value of `storeid` from `getid` or make it a global variable.

Comment: @NickParsons Ok. I removed the function and only left `var storeid = window.location.hash.substr(1);`. But it still doesn't work.
I updated the code snippet.

Comment: @Wolffe2 are you getting any errors in your console? - Usually "doesn't work" or "not working" is a pretty vague description of the issue.Try and add error messages whenever possible and describe exactly what isn't working.

Comment: @NickParsons I had a spelling mistake in the hash. Now every thing works fine. Thank you so much.